# Model incompatibility while retraining an older model with updated data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, chatbot

I am making an AI chatbot in Python, and came across a problem with incompatibility of the older model (which was trained by me on the same exact code a few days ago) on updated data.
Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import keras

text_data = open('data.txt', 'r', encoding = "utf-8").read()
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text_data])
total_words = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
input_sequences = []
for line in text_data.split('\n'):
    token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([line])[0]
    for i in range(1, len(token_list)):
        n_gram_sequence = token_list[:i+1]
        input_sequences.append(n_gram_sequence)

max_sequence_len = max([len(seq) for seq in input_sequences])
input_sequences = pad_sequences(input_sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_len, padding='pre')

input_sequences = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_sequences)
xs, labels = input_sequences[:, :-1], input_sequences[:, -1]
ys = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=total_words)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(total_words, 100, input_length=max_sequence_len-1),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(150)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(total_words, activation='softmax')
])

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('almond.h5')

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=20)

model.save('almond.h5')
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-35235876347e> in <cell line: 41>()
     39 # Compile and train the model
     40 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 41 model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=20)
     42 
     43 # Save the trained model

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1984, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5559, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 2874) and (None, 2819) are incompatible
```

I understand that the older model is incompatible with the new data due to the data's new length and vocabulary size, but is there a way to fix that?

I figured that the model's layers were maybe untrainable, so that's why I added this:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
```

Comment: The trained-model must always take the same input shape data that he was trained on previously, thus in your case you will not be able to use the model as it is on a different shape input data. Nevertheless, you could try decompose the trained model layers to be attached on some input layers by you on the new data.